# Getting list of keys in the JSON column

Tags: postgresql

What's the function analogous to JavaScript's `Object.keys(...)` that returns the list of keys of the specified object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`json_object_keys` or `jsonb_object_keys`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) function.